# Create a zip file entirely in memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, zip, php-ziparchive

**Is it possible to create a zip file purely memory in ios ? it should not depends any directory ? .**

I have tried many framework nothing helps all frameworks depends a local repository

Comment: It is a bad idea to load a whole file in memory. It can lead to memory issues. so, it is better to write it in disk instead of in memory.

Comment: Whats wrong with writing it to a temporary url ?

Comment: Yes indeed Parth Bhuva. but is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's more of a library recommendation. The [minizip](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip) library supports this. There's a framework [Minizip](https://github.com/dexman/Minizip) which wraps it. I'll echo the 'but why' on this - there is limited memory on iOS devices.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for your answer.  but depending only on URL. is there any way around there ?

Comment: Again why don't you write your data to a temporary location? If you don't want to use a temporary folder, just write your file, load it to memory and then delete the file from disk. the file will exit for just a fraction of a second.

Comment: Note that if load the data you would still need to have a reference to the original url otherwise you would be discarding the file name

Comment: The problem is when saving to disk via app sandbox the zip file can be viewed by testers. also our app is more privacy to hold users data. That is then only thing i am trying to save it to memory. so please help me out.

Comment: @Petesh Thanks for ur answer. can you please suggest me a code snippet for to access minizip library or some other framework, because i am not good at c programming. also it is taking a local path to create a zip.

Comment: Well if security is concern then why don't you encrypt the file and save encrypted file to temp location. That way no one can read your file and you can decrypt the file to use it again.